# Is uniqueidentifier unique across databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a number of database where each have an audit table. One of these databases is a 'common' database that has tables such as countries, states, etc.

The tables of this common database are reference in the other databases as views.

Currently my audit table has an identity column. For listing audit records, I use a UNION to union the audit table in the normal database and audit table in the common database.

However the identity column in audit tables might be the same.

If I add a uniqueidentifier column in the audit table and use that as my unique id, will this column be unique across databases?

Comment: ... and are they statistically unique across the multiverse? How much chaos does that require?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the built-in methods of `uniqueidentifier` generation (like `newId()` or C#'s `Guid.NewGuid()`), yes, it will be unique across databases, servers, countries, whatever.

In fact, that's one of the big uses of GUIDs - replication. If you have the same GUID in two databases, it's guaranteed that it was put there on purpose.

However, do note that GUIDs do have their shortcomings - they might make your indices perform worse (or at least require more maintenance), and they are bigger in general.

Also, GUIDs aren't *entirely* random - there's a few different GUID generating algorithms, some of which are inherently unique (e.g. using a MAC address as part of the GUID - MACs are unique by default, although you can override them manually) - so one part is unique per physical server, and the machine makes sure it doesn't use the same timestamp for two GUIDs. There's also sequential GUIDs (`newSequentialId()`), which are handy in avoiding index fragmentation (very useful for clustered indices of course) - do note that those depend on the MAC address of the computer, and they are predictable, so if you're making the GUID public, and you depend on them being "secret", you might not want to use those. Some GUID algorithms are more predictable than others.

Comment: Might be worth adding that you should NOT use the NEWSEQUENTIALID() function - this won't achieve what the OP wants.

Comment: @RhysJones Actually, `newSequentialId` is unique across machines, but only if there's a hardware to distinguish them -  MAC address of the network card. Servers tend to have unique MAC address.

Comment: @RhysJones But yeah, sequential GUIDs have their own issues (just like all the other GUIDs).

Answer (score 1):

It is universally unique. It is a random-generated string of 32 chars making a possibility of having a duplicate as 1 / (16^32).

There is no certain mechanism to create uniqueness, extremeley low probability does it all.

Comment: Actually, there are several mechanisms to guarantee uniqueness - if you follow the proper algorithms. Of course, I've seen a lot of GUID libraries that do what you said - generate a random string of 16 bytes. That's *not* a real GUID. A good sanity check is looking at the version number - if it's not there, it's probably a bad GUID. Only version 4 standard GUIDs fit your definition, although of course they still have the proper structure with a version, so you're not getting the full 16 bytes - the six bits don't make a whole lot of difference, though, of course.

Comment: That'a proper response. Of course as @luuan has told there is no exact randomness in physical computer device and randomness is generated by means of computation, some use random-genrating algorithms, some use more generic ways to generate guid as you have told. But I did not mean to overengineer the answer. In my humble opinion as far as you won't be deciding on the best way to generate guid or not making science of it, just accepting that its uniqueness comes from smallr probability is enough. Tht's why I have just answered in this way.